dnf missng groups or modules
I am trying to install PostgreSQL on CentOS-7, but when I'm trying to select a version like this:
sudo dnf module enable postgresql:13

I'm getting respond:
Failed to set locale, defaulting to C
PostgreSQL 13 for RHEL / Rocky / AlmaLinux 7 - x86_64                                                                                                                                                         0.0  B/s |   0  B     00:00    
PostgreSQL 13 for RHEL / Rocky / AlmaLinux 7 - x86_64                                                                                                                                                         0.0  B/s |   0  B     00:00    
PostgreSQL 13 for RHEL / Rocky / AlmaLinux 7 - x86_64                                                                                                                                                         0.0  B/s |   0  B     00:00    
PostgreSQL 12 for RHEL / Rocky / AlmaLinux 7 - x86_64                                                                                                                                                         0.0  B/s |   0  B     00:00    
PostgreSQL 12 for RHEL / Rocky / AlmaLinux 7 - x86_64                                                                                                                                                         0.0  B/s |   0  B     00:00    
PostgreSQL 12 for RHEL / Rocky / AlmaLinux 7 - x86_64                                                                                                                                                         0.0  B/s |   0  B     00:00    
PostgreSQL 14 for RHEL / Rocky / AlmaLinux 7 - x86_64                                                                                                                                                         0.0  B/s |   0  B     00:00    
PostgreSQL 14 for RHEL / Rocky / AlmaLinux 7 - x86_64                                                                                                                                                         0.0  B/s |   0  B     00:00    
PostgreSQL 14 for RHEL / Rocky / AlmaLinux 7 - x86_64                                                                                                                                                         0.0  B/s |   0  B     00:00    
PostgreSQL 16 for RHEL / Rocky / AlmaLinux 7 - x86_64                                                                                                                                                         0.0  B/s |   0  B     00:00    
PostgreSQL common RPMs for RHEL / Rocky / AlmaLinux 7 - x86_64                                                                                                                                                0.0  B/s |   0  B     00:00    
PostgreSQL common RPMs for RHEL / Rocky / AlmaLinux 7 - x86_64                                                                                                                                                0.0  B/s |   0  B     00:00    
PostgreSQL common RPMs for RHEL / Rocky / AlmaLinux 7 - x86_64                                                                                                                                                0.0  B/s |   0  B     00:00    
PostgreSQL 15 for RHEL / Rocky / AlmaLinux 7 - x86_64                                                                                                                                                         0.0  B/s |   0  B     00:00    
PostgreSQL 15 for RHEL / Rocky / AlmaLinux 7 - x86_64                                                                                                                                                         0.0  B/s |   0  B     00:00    
PostgreSQL 15 for RHEL / Rocky / AlmaLinux 7 - x86_64                                                                                                                                                         0.0  B/s |   0  B     00:00    
Failed to synchronize cache for repo 'pgdg13', ignoring this repo.
Failed to synchronize cache for repo 'pgdg12', ignoring this repo.
Failed to synchronize cache for repo 'pgdg14', ignoring this repo.
Failed to synchronize cache for repo 'pgdg16', ignoring this repo.
Failed to synchronize cache for repo 'pgdg-common', ignoring this repo.
Failed to synchronize cache for repo 'pgdg15', ignoring this repo.
Last metadata expiration check: 1:00:00 ago on Wed May 29 10:55:34 2024.
Error: Problems in request:
missing groups or modules: postgresql:13

Repo List looks like this (with first lines equal to respond of module command):
sudo dnf repolist
...                                                                                                                                                         
repo id                                                                                    repo name                                                                                                                                    status
base                                                                                       CentOS-7 - Base                                                                                                                              10072
*epel                                                                                      Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64                                                                                               13787
extras                                                                                     CentOS-7 - Extras                                                                                                                              526
remi-safe                                                                                  Safe Remi's RPM repository for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64                                                                                    5596
updates                                                                                    CentOS-7 - Updates                                                                                                                            5886

I tried to install manually pgdg-redhat-repo but this didn't helped.

I don't think you have to enable any modules. Just follow the instructions.

1/ CentOS 7 will reach its end of life on June 30, 2024 in 1 month
See https://blog.centos.org/2023/04/end-dates-are-coming-for-centos-stream-8-and-centos-linux-7/
So migrating to a supported distro is recommended
2/ "module" is a CentOS 8 and 9 feature
3/ CentOS 7 use yum; not dnf
Even is some dnf packages exist, it have very partial support
(IIUC, mostly designed for distro upgrade)
